# Faking GetCallingAssembly() to point to a different assembly

Tags: c#, security

I'm a developer of a game in c#, and I have a security feature in which my server dynamically creates a DLL with some secret keys in it and uploads this DLL to amazon s3, and then pushes out challenges to people are random. When the clients receive this challenge they have 30 seconds to respond.

The clients download the DLL from amazon s3, and using reflection call a method, which takes in a key sent to them by the server.

The dll then takes the key passed into the function, the secret key randomly built into the dll, and a crc hash of the `GetCallingAssembly()` and hashes them together. This result is returned to the client and the client pushes the response back to the server.

Back to the question... We have a hacker who has somehow found a way to fake `GetCallingAssembly` and to better understand this, so that I may find a way to prevent it or use something a little harder to fake, I would like to replicate what he did.

From what I've gained its an application he is using, he did NOT use code to do this. But i have found NOTHING in regards to this. Any help with be greatly appreciated so that i can remove this guys security hole.

Comment: Why don't you send him a job offer?

Comment: I've offered this, while he would come on board im positive he has stated he will not reveal how he is doing what he is doing.

Comment: One way to do things like this is with a detouring framework like Moles, which can dedirect the implementation of any static method.  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Comment: It also wouldn't be too difficult to disassemble your downloaded DLL to its IL, replace the call to GetCallingAssembly to a constant loading of the expected values, then recompile and use that.  There are tools to do this with the machine code as well, though those kinds of detours are a bit more involved.

Comment: You would need to decompile on the fly, since the DLL CONSTANTLY changes, roughly every 15 minutes or so.

Comment: For info on on-the-fly IL rewriting, check out Cecil.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271674/Introduction-to-IL-Rewriting-with-Cecil-Part-1-Rew  There are other tools that do this, as well, as it's commonly used to implement AOP frameworks.

Comment: Rather than relying on [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), you should try to make your game so safe that even if people could see the source code in its entirety it wouldn't be a problem. That's [how modern cryptography works.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_by_design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of techniques that could be used for this.  For example, the [Moles framework](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/default.aspx) allows one to replace the implementation of even static methods on BCL assemblies.  It accomplishes this via use of a CLR profiler, which may or may not be what your hacker has done.

Comment: Is there away to UN-hijack it? Or determine if it has been hijacked?

Comment: @willthiswork89, possibly, but every countermeasure can of course be countered by determining what it's looking for and detouring/rewriting the checks to succeed.  The real moral of the story is that you can't prevent hacking of a client, so never trust the client to do anything important.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only thing you'd have to do in order to trick `GetCallingAssembly` would be to create a new assembly with the same name. Now the chain is broken. I can't point to how he did it, but I can provide a suggestion to make it more difficult to crack...

1. Client downloads DLL from S3
2. Client invokes method in the DLL
3. DLL gets the calling assembly, and invokes a method on the client. This method takes in some salt (preferably one of the unique keys in the DLL or a datetime), appends it to a secret string (stored in the client), hashes the result, and returns this hash to the DLL.
4. Once the client provides the correct result, then the DLL answers the server correctly.

It's always possible to break in, but the more encryption-related steps in-between, the more difficult you make it for them. And this step wouldn't take much effort to add.

Comment: If the Calling Assembly is fakes and points to the real deal somewhere else on the computer, then it will still generate the correct response thus making what you have suggested pointless. He has faked the calling assembly to point to the REAL game, while his modified one is the actual one running.

Comment: Also, im doing GetCallingAssembly.Location, then using the bytes of the file, generating a CRC which is what i use to verify its the real game.

Comment: So it's a man in the middle, he's just pretending to play both sides? If so, that makes it much more difficult to circumvent...

Comment: Pretty much, he hacks the game, and somehow has faked the GetCallingAssembly to point to the real assembly, so when he invokes the dll from his game as he normally would the dll sees getcallingassembly points to the real game somehow and so my dll hashes the real game

Comment: You have just made me think of an idea, from within the dll what if we looked at the processes currently running and ensure the unaltered game and path are in the running process list? We bind to specific ports for the game to run properly so by doing this, he would have trouble with opening the same port twice.

Comment: I was trying to think of something like that, and it could definitely work. But if he's good enough to patch the game to begin with, he can probably tunnel the correct process to a different port to get it to appear to be running.

Comment: It's almost like you need a 2-way process - your client needs to know some sort of secret to be able to respond; is it possible to send that secret via the TCP connection? So, client gets the latest secret, which he must then use to respond correctly to the DLL. Secret could update as often as the DLL.

Comment: Hmm we could do that, my requiring it to response via a TCP Connection it would require it to be running, and the game gets updates weekly, we could change the secret key occasionally. and since its built into the dll which changes very often, he would have trouble decompiling on the fly programatically.

Comment: It's still possible to circumvent, but it would require him to modify his setup as often as the game changes, and even then it might require him to do some extra work to wire it up correctly. The key is to make it too annoying for him to deal with.